# Process Builder - Update Parent Account Field Based on all Child Statuses

Tags: process-builder

I have Parent Accounts and Child Accounts.
Accounts have two checkbox fields, Account_Active and is_Parent.

I want to do the following:
If the account is a parent account:

- And at least one child account has an Account_Active checkbox true, make the Account_Active of the parent true
- And all child accounts have an Account_Active checkbox false, make the Account_Active of the parent false

Is this possible to complete in process builder? I'm a bit confused over needing to check all related child accounts.

Comment: you need to use Lightning Flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible through Process Builder or not, but this strikes me as something better handled by the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), or you might need to resort to Apex (likely as part of a trigger).

The concern I'd have with Process Builder is that it would need to query child records *for each parent record that Process Builder runs on* (again, that's assuming you could query child records). In other words, it'd be like having a query inside a loop (which is bad, it makes you unable to handle more than 100 records at a time).

You could accomplish this by using the DLRS tool to count the number of child records with `Account_Active__c` set to `true`. After that, you could easily use Process Builder to do a simple update on the parent (if isParent and activeChildCount = 0, update active to false, else update active to true).

Comment: After reviewing, this is actually a bit different. Child Accounts aren't actually children of 'Accounts', so when I try to use rollup, I can't choose 'accounts' as the subset.